# Segmentation fault in program of threads

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p23Zp.jpg)

can someone please help me why it says "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" when I start the program?

Comment: Please post the code and not am image to the code. You want us to help you for free so make it as easy possible for us to do this

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to pthread_create is incorrect. It should not be thread_id[i], it should be the address of thread_id[i].